# Oracle Scheduler - repeat interval 2 different days and times

Tags: oracle, scheduler, frequency, jobs, repeat

is it possible create job with repeat interval in 2 different days and times in one job?
For example each MON at 02:00: AM and each FRI at 03:00 PM.

```
repeat_interval      =>  'FREQ=DAILY;BYDAY=MON;
                          byhour=02; byminute=00; bysecond=00',

repeat_interval      =>  'FREQ=DAILY;BYDAY=FRI;
                          byhour=15; byminute=00; bysecond=00',
```

these frequencies, but together in one job repeat_interval.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a named schedule for one of interval and use INCLUDE like

Edited version:
Because of `INCLUDE` doesn't support `byminute, byhour` .etc I changed it like this, what I done, described first job as a  dayly, fires on each Friday, but added a start timestamp, and pointed a time. so it repeats at that time each Friday, and than include it into second job.

```
declare
   ts timestamp := to_timestamp_tz('28/04/2017 09:00:00',
                                   'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
begin

   dbms_scheduler.create_schedule('FRIDAY_SCHED', start_date => ts,
                                  repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYDAY=FRI;');
   dbms_scheduler.create_schedule('ALL_SCHED',
                                  repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYDAY=MON; byhour=02; byminute=00; bysecond=00;INCLUDE=FRIDAY_SCHED');
end;
```

You can test the period in this way

```
declare
   start_date timestamp;
   return_date_after timestamp;
   next_run_date timestamp;
begin
   start_date := to_timestamp_tz('28/04/2017 09:00:00',
                                   'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
   return_date_after := start_date;
   for i in 1 .. 5 loop
      DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING('FREQ=DAILY;BYDAY=FRI;',
                                              start_date, return_date_after,
                                              next_run_date);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('next_run_date: ' || next_run_date);
      return_date_after := next_run_date;
   end loop;
end;
```

Comment: It doesn't work. 27422. 00000 -  "usage of %s not supported in embedded calendar application \"%s\".\"%s\""
*Cause:    The main calendar definition used an embedded calendar in an INCLUDE,
           EXCLUDE, INTERSECT, or FREQ clause for which extra limitations
           apply.
*Action:   Remove the specific clause from the calendar definition.